# How to remove project name in the route name in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I would like to ask if how to remove the project name in the route name. I went through a tutorial and follow each practice sessions and when I tried to post the registration that went like this:

```
<form action = "/user/register" method = "post">
     <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "<?php echo csrf_token() ?>">

     <table>
        <tr>
           <td>Name</td>
           <td><input type = "text" name = "name" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
           <td>Username</td>
           <td><input type = "text" name = "username" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
           <td>Password</td>
           <td><input type = "text" name = "password" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
           <td colspan = "2" align = "center">
              <input type = "submit" value = "Register" />
           </td>
        </tr>
     </table>

  </form>
```

but when I posted it, it showed an error saying the url was not found so I added the project name in the url: `/test_laravel/user/register` is the new action. Well it worked but how to get rid of this?

Thanks!

Comment: <form method="post" action="{{ action('Yourcontroller@function') }}" accept-charset="UTF-8">

Comment: thanks @Shanukk, but it throws an an error. This is the new action: ``{{ action('UserRegistrationController@postRegister') }}``.

Comment: Route::post('/', array('as' => 'postRegister', 'uses' => 'UserRegistrationController@postRegister')); in route

Comment: still it doesn't work. Might there will be something to configure in some files?

Comment: can you please paste your error

Comment: Read documentation everything can be found there...

Answer (score 1):

To make a proper URL you can use:

[route()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-route)

> The `url` function generates a fully qualified URL to the given path:

```
$url = route('routeName');
$url = route('routeName', ['id' => 1]);
```

or [url()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-url)

> The url function generates a full$url = route('routeName', ['id' => 1]);y qualified URL to the given path

```
echo url('user/profile');
echo url('user/profile', [1]);
```

or [action()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-action)

> The `action` function generates a URL for the given controller action. You do not need to pass the full namespace to the controller. Instead, pass the controller class name relative to the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace:

```
$url = action('HomeController@getIndex');
$url = action('UserController@profile', ['id' => 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is why routes are designed.

Make a route file;

```
Route::post('user/registration',['uses' => 'ControllerName@MethodName','as' => 'giveRouteAUniqueName']);

uses accepts controller name and after @ accepts method(function) of the controller
and as gives you ability to assign new unique name to route now you can call
route('RouteName'); in our case its route('giveRouteAUniqueName')
```